# how to throw exception with system() in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, exception

I am trying to use

```
system("mkdir -p a/b/c/d")
```

in C++ to create a directory in linux. I currently do not have much understanding of C++'s exception handling process. What is the proper way to use try/catch to throw an exception, and what exception should I throw, in case the command execution fails?

Comment: You could use [mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir). Or (better) [create_directory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory)

Comment: system() will not throw anything. If you want to throw something if it fails, what you throw is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier to use, much safer, and also well-defined is [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (or [`<experimental/filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) in C++17).  Please use this solution.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    fs::create_directories("/tmp/path/to/dir");
    fs::create_directories("/dev/null");
}
```

---

The return value of `system` is implementation defined, but generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command.  So if your command returns something else than `0` it failed.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    if ( std::system("mkdir -p /tmp/path/to/dir") != 0 )
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not create directory");

    if ( std::system("mkdir -p /dev/null") != 0 )
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not create directory");
}
```